# Refactor instance declaration from try block to above try block in a method

Tags: visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper

Often I find myself coming across code like this:

```
try
{
  StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter();
}
```

However, there is no reference to the object outside the scope of the try block. How could I refactor (extract to field in Visual Studio says there is no field or something) the statement in the try block so that it is declared above the try block so I can use it anywhere in the method?

Thanks

Comment: You could resort to plain old Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to split the declaration and assignment.  If you have Resharper, there's a method to do the split, but you'll have to move it manually:

```
StreamWriter strw = null;
try
{
    strw = new StreamWriter();
}
catch()
{ // ...
```

Often, adding the (technically useless) `= null;` is required, as well, to prevent potential warnings about using variables before assignment, due to the assignment being in a different scope.  This depends a bit on how you're using the data, though.

Also, since `StreamWriter` is IDisposable, you'll want to make sure that you have a finally block that does the disposal, or place the the entire usage in a `using` block.

Comment: That won't compile. "strw" is declared twice. Remove "StreamWriter" from inside the try {}  and it should be fine.

Comment: Hi. StreamWriter is just an example type, am aware of the IDisposable issue. Thanks :) I don't have Resharper at the moment, waiting for the final release of 5.0 so I can get it for 2010.

Comment: @dotnetdev: You can get the RC for free right now... http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/beta/beta.html

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter strw = null;
try
{
  strw = new StreamWriter();
}
```

But for a `StreamWriter` (which is `IDisposable`) it is even better to use the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx)-keyword:

```
using( StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter() )
{
  ..
}
```